# Remove extra space on li and li:hover background images

Tags: html, css

I have created a navigation bar using background images and hover effects. I'm trying to learn how to implement them properly on a website.

I've designed 90% of the navigation but the problem I'm having is that when I hover over one of the items the hover image doesn't overlap the original and creates extra space.

**CSS :**

```
#bg {
    background-color: #EAEAEA;
    width: 761px;
}
#menu {
    background-color: #EAEAEA;
    height: 58px;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-left: 1px;
}
#menu li.first a {
    background: url("../images/top_nav_f.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    height: 180px;
}
#menu li a {
    background: url("../images/top_nav_f.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    float: left;
    width: 190px;
    height: 180px;
}
#menu li.first a:hover {
    background: url("../images/menu_hover_f.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
} 
#menu li a:hover {
    background: url("../images/menu_hover.png") no-repeat scroll right top transparent;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    height: 58px;
}
#menu li.last a {
    background: url("../images/top_nav_n.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
}
#menu li.last a:hover {
    background: url("../images/menu_hover_r.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
}
.bar {
    margin-right: 38px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    text-align: center;
}
.n1, .n2 {
    color: #333333;
}
```

**HTML :**

```
  <nav id="bg">
            <ul id="menu">
           <li class="first">
            <a href="">
            <div class="bar">
              <div class="n2">Link 1 </div>
            </div>
           </a>

           </li>

            <li><a class="" href="">
            <div class="bar">
              <div class="n2">link 2 </div>
            </div>
             </a>
             </li>

            <li><a class="" href="">
            <div class="bar">
              <div class="n2">link 3 </div>
            </div>
            </a>
            </li>


             <li class="last"><a href="">
            <div class="bar">
              <div class="n2">link 4 </div>
            </div>
            </a>
            </li>
</ul>

</nav>
```

Demo: http://tinyurl.com/cqus3fb

I've been trying to get this to work for almost 3 days!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the `#menu li a:hover` rule below:

```
#menu li a:hover {
    background: url("../images/menu_hover.png") no-repeat scroll right top transparent;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    height: 58px;
}
```

You need to change your background rule to:

```
    background: url("../images/menu_hover.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
```

The reason is that in your shorthand declaration of the background you have set your background position to be `right` and `top` where as all of the other rules are set to `0` and `0`. So basically your background is being positioned from the right instead of the left and as the `a` is 190px wide and the image is 180px wide it makes it seem like there is a 10px gap.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I did as u said but i still see the gap. it would have been easy if it was just boxes but coz if this arrow like shape i cant get it work. i think its the image shape is causing the issue now. is there another way to adjoin the images to achieve the results?